# RubyでJSONの配列を結合した後にソートしたい

Tags: ruby, json

Rubyで二つのJSON配列 `a`, `b` を `+` 演算子によって結合し、`c = a + b` という配列を作りました。
その後で `c` を "id" というキーの値でソートしたいのですが、うまくソートされてくれません。

以下に試したことと結果を記載するので、もしお分かりの方はご教授頂けると幸いです。

#### 試したこと

```rb
a = [{id: 10000, name: "aaa"}, {id: 15000, name: "zzz"}]
b = [{id: 12000, name: "bbb"}, {id: 20000, name: "yyy"}]

c = a + b
=> [{:id=>10000, :name=>"aaa"}, {:id=>15000, :name=>"zzz"}, {:id=>12000, :name=>"bbb"}, {:id=>20000, :name=>"yyy"}]

c.sort_by{|a| a["id"]}.reverse
=> [{:id=>20000, :name=>"yyy"}, {:id=>12000, :name=>"bbb"}, {:id=>15000, :name=>"zzz"}, {:id=>10000, :name=>"aaa"}]

=======

↓（本当はこのようにソートされて欲しい）
[{:id=>20000, :name=>"yyy"}, {:id=>15000, :name=>"zzz"}, {:id=>12000, :name=>"bbb"} {:id=>10000, :name=>"aaa"}]
```

Comment: 参考までに、ruby 1.9 以上であれば hash key の順序が登録順になっていますので、`c.sort_by(&:first).reverse` などとする事もできます。

Answer (score 3):

SymbolがキーのHashの配列のように見えます。そのため `a["id"]` では`a[:id]` の値がうまく取れずソートできていなさそうです。

```
a = {id: 10000, name: "aaa"}
# => {:id=>10000, :name=>"aaa"}
a["id"]
# => nil
a[:id]
# => 10000
```

`sort_by` に渡すブロックをこのように変更してはいかがでしょうか

```
c.sort_by{|a| a[:id]}.reverse
```

Comment: うまくソートできました！初歩的なミスでした...
助かりました、ありがとうございます！mm

Comment: 回答を承認してもらえると嬉しいです https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers